# How to rewrite Git URL for submodules that haven't yet been cloned?

Tags: git, github, url-rewriting, git-submodules, ssh-keys

I have a Git superproject with a submodule, which itself contains a submodule.  Everything is in private GitHub repositories and is accessed via HTTPS.  This means that the URLs stored in `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` are HTTPS-formatted.  I am writing a mini build server that needs to pull the latest code, but it needs to use SSH deploy keys since it's not a human who can enter GitHub passwords.

Establishing a Git URL rewriting rule works for the superproject, but it seems to be ignored by the submodules if they haven't already been cloned:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/user/superproject.git
$ cd superproject
$ git config url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/
$ ssh-agent sh -c "ssh-add id_rsa-deploy-key && git submodule update submod1"
```

The `git submodule update` in that last line ignores the URL rewrite rule, uses HTTPS, and prompts for a GitHub account & password.

Now, if the repository tree has already been cloned once (like with `git submodule update --init --recursive`, using HTTPS), then the URL rewriting rules do work correctly and it will use SSH.  How can URL rewriting be used for the initial submodule clone, though?

Comment: set the `git config` globally on the deploy machine (before cloning `superproject`).